# Make numbers of $5$ digits using digits $1,2$ and $3$. What is the sum of all these numbers?

Tags: combinatorics

I'm re-reading some excercises I've made in high school about combinatorics and I've discovered one exercise which I can't for the life of me solve properly.

Basically, the question boils down to this:

> With the digits $1,2$ and $3$ you can make numbers of $5$ digits. What is the sum of all these numbers?

Can anyone help me out here? I'm stumped!

Comment: I deleted my comment. Of course, one of them has to be repeated because there are 5 letters and only three choices.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first digit can be $1,2,3$. The second digit can be $1,2,3$, etc. all the way up to the fifth digit. There are $243$ such $5$-digit numbers, hence the numbers $1,2,3$ appear $81$ times in each position while enumerating these numbers. Hence, the answer would be:
$$
(1+2+3)(81)(1+10+100+1000+10000) = 486 \times 11111 = 5399946
$$

Comment: Well explained! In the end not that hard, but as always with combinatorics, you have to "see" it, thanks :)

Comment: @querty You are welcome.